# In a Facebook-like social network programmed in Rails, where in the database would you store that a user "likes" a Page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

I'm creating a social network in Rails. I have a User model and a Page model. Users can "follow" or subscribe to Pages. So a user can have many pages and a page can have many users. How would these relationships be stored in the database? Do I need to create a new object Subscription which belongs_to :user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is done with a "join model", which would be UserPage, and a user_pages table. You could call it Subscription if you wanted, but Rails will reward you for sticking to its expected semantics.

Comment: Thanks. So I can make a new model, call it UserPage, give it a user_id and page_id, and optionally some other properties of the subscription. Then a user can have  has_many :pages, :through=>:userpages , right?

Comment: Close. User has_many :user_pages; has_many :pages, :through => :user_pages. Other properties can then be set on the join record.